# Handling many If else Conditions in a single mule flow

Tags: mule

I have to call another teams one System API, with different query parameters based on different conditions. .
I am adding different conditions ( for now 15 , count may increase in future ) in Choice Router based on which I am calling the same SAPI with different query parameters.

But Choice Router is becoming very cumbersome and my flow is looking ugly.

Please suggest any other good way to handle this scenario.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please reconsider your question and take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
This board is about helping others with their coding-problems. What have you done so far? Please show us the codelines you have written so far concerning the problem. If you have errors or warnings please show them to us as well.

Comment: As @Melvin suggested, adding examples of the logic will increase the chances of an useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

One approach I can think of is to abstract the System API into its own flow which expects a flowVar JSON variable (`sapiParameters`) which has all the expected parameters. Like:

```
{
    param1: "hello", 
    param2: "world", 
    ...
}
```

Then you can move the conditional logic into transformers that create this flowVar variable `sapiParameters`.

These transformers could be dataweave transformers, but can also become Java classes or groovy scripts if the logic becomes too complex.

Answer (score 0):

Try using match..case operator for removing multiple if..else logic. Based on your conditions, you can pass different query parameters passed to your calling API.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-pattern-matching

Answer (score -1):

Another approach, I can think of DataWeave using

> if,else If,else or using pattern Matching using match operator

```
<ee:transform doc:name="Choice alternative" doc:id="230-3-kke9" >
<ee:message >
  </ee:message>
  <ee:variables >
    <ee:set-variable variableName="choiceFlow" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
if(<condition1>)
  Mule::lookup('flow1', {test:'hello '})
else if (<conditional2>)
  Mule::lookup('flow2', {test:'hello '})
else
  Mule::lookup('flow3', {test:'hello '})]]></ee:set-variable>
  </ee:variables>
</ee:transform>
```

Internal workings of the DataWeave engine might cause a lookup function to be invoked in parallel with other lookup functions, or not to be invoked at all.

**MuleSoft recommends that you invoke flows with the Flow Ref (flow-ref) component**

```
Please Note: You can add more else if in above code.
```

Comment: Never ever use DataWeave lookup() function for flow control. It will potentially cause thread exhaustion. It is designed for lookup values quickly, not flow control. Absolutely not recommend.

Comment: Yes,correct ,Absolutely agree, That's why I mention the MuleSoft recommendation.